# Unable to change background of navbar on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to web-dev and I am trying to change the background color from transparent to blue upon scrolling. I am using bootstrap. I tried using this JavaScript code but it didn't work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){       
 var scroll_start = 0;
 var startchange = $('#startchange');
 var offset = startchange.offset();
 if (startchange.length){
 $(document).scroll(function() { 
  scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
      $("nav.navbar div.container-fluid").css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
   } else {
      $("nav.navbar div.container-fluid").css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
 });
}
```

This is the html code I am using

```
<nav class="navbar" data-spy="affix">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/rubix-logo-navy.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is the CSS

```
nav.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  border: none; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    nav.navbar {
      position: static;
      top: 0; 
      } }
  nav.navbar div.container-fluid {
    background-color: transparent; }
  nav.navbar button.navbar-toggle span.icon-bar {
    color: #002776;
    border-color: #002776;
    background-color: #002776; }
  nav.navbar a.navbar-brand {
    color: #002776;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px; }
    nav.navbar a.navbar-brand img {
      width: 125px; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      nav.navbar a.navbar-brand {
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        font-size: 16px; } }
  nav.navbar ul.nav li a {
    color: #002776;
    transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px; }
    nav.navbar ul.nav li a:hover {
      color: #00a1de;
      background-color: transparent; }
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    nav.navbar.affix {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 100; } }

   nav.navbar div.container-fluid.top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background: #000;
    }
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: I just organized your code, corrected a javascript error it has, but I don't understand what's that that you want to achieve. In your HTML there is not #startchange element: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOBdEy

Comment: Hi ! I have s #startchange element later on, so that the colour changes once it passes that element.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to change your Nav background when you scroll down, and change it back when you scroll to the top? If i am correct, then this may be the edit you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
 var scroll_start = 0;
 var offset = $("body").offset();
 $(document).scroll(function() {  
  scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll_start > offset.top) { 
      $("nav.navbar div.container-fluid").css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
   } else {
      $("nav.navbar div.container-fluid").css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hi ! That's exactly what I want,  but when I tried your function, it just remains transparent through out.

Comment: Hi!  It seems to be working on fiddle but I am unable to replicate this on my website.  Is it probably because I have placed the above HTML code in the body?

Comment: HTML code should be in the <body> section, css should be in the <head> section, jQuery code should come after the JQuery.min.js file has been linked. Just as the sample Bootstrap layouts on their website.